# Remove double quotes from string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to grab data from a MySQL database and use Ruby to reformat it into a flat text file. Some of my MySQL data contains double quotes like so:

> `Matthew "Matt" Perry`

and I need to remove those quotes and replace them with something else, | for instance.

I found another post on stackoverflow about removing quotes that suggested the following:

```
s.scan(/'(.+?)'|"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)/).flatten.compact
```

but that returns the string intact (with double quotes). How can I get

> `Matthew |Matt| Perry`

instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will do it if you don't want to modify `s`:

```
new_s = s.gsub /"/, '|'
```

If you do want to modify `s`:

```
s.gsub! /"/, '|'
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like:

```
text = 'Matthew "Matt" Perry'

text.tr(%q{"'}, '|') # => "Matthew |Matt| Perry"

text = "Matthew 'Matt' Perry"
text.tr(%q{"'}, '|') # => "Matthew |Matt| Perry"
```

Comment: SO's syntax highlighter failed again )

Answer (score 0):

It removes doublequotes. You can see them in IRB or when using `p` only because string are being showed for you in these cases in *nice* form, allowing you to see, that they are strings.

```
irb> 'Matthew "Matt" Perry'.scan(/'(.+?)'|"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)/).flatten.compact
=> ["Matthew", "Matt", "Perry"]
```

In real, they already don't have doublequotes.

```
irb> puts 'Matthew "Matt" Perry'.scan(/'(.+?)'|"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)/).flatten.compact
Matthew
Matt
Perry
=> nil
```

And to replace doublequotes with dash, you may use [`.tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001199):

```
irb> 'Matthew "Matt" Perry'.tr '"','|'
=> "Matthew |Matt| Perry"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other choices are:

```
s.tr! '"', '|'
s2 = s.tr '"', '|'
```