# Removing Double-Quotes with Ruby and Rails and .gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, special-characters, gsub

Im using ruby and rails to automatically create a filename from the name of the product and the product's variant-type. Using .gsub, the filename will be lowercase and have special characters (spaces, ', -) removed.  Ive got most of it working but I can't seem to get it to remove double quotes.

This works for single quotes:

```
"'"
```

But this doesn't work for double-quotes:

```
'"'
```

Here's my code:

```
 filepath_name = product.name+"_"+variant_type.gsub(/ /,'').gsub("'", "").gsub("-", "").gsub('"', '').downcase+".mpg"
```

Comment: This has been asked before.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720401/remove-double-quotes-from-string -- Working answer :)

Comment: rails has a built in method `parameterize` see http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/String/parameterize - not sure if perfect fit for your case since it does use '-', anyhow, maybe something like this? `filepath_name = "#{product.name}_#{variant_type.parameterize}".gsub("-", "")` - otherwise I would use @Jason Truluck example

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a regexp to remove anything but ascii characters like:

```
variant_type.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z.\-]/, '')
```

and modify it to suit your needs. You can use [rubular](http://rubular.com/) for a reference.